# when I will type the first row 3 input box then those values are shown in the display name input box

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, web

when I will type the first row 3 input box then those values are shown in the display name input box.

[image]

```
var output = $('.keyupDisplay');

    
    $('.keyupName').keyup( function() {   
        output.val(function () {
            return $('.keyupName').map(function () {
                return this.value;
            }).get();
        });
    });
```

It is shown on the display input box but shows with "," separation. **Like Mr,Motalib,Hossain**
I need the result like this **Like Mr Motalib Hossain**

Comment: Why did you un-accept my answer?

Comment: Sorry, your reply has been deleted by mistake while I am giving you thanks.

Comment: Just click on the ✓ under the counter on the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75004897/295783

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use join
- Cache the fields
- Also no need to use a function inside the val
- Use `input` since it also handles paste
- Lastly, don't name a field after what you decided to use to interrogate it. As we see it can change

```js
const $displayName = $('.displayName')
const $names = $('.personName').on('input', function() {
  $displayName.val(
    $names
    .map(function() { return this.value; })
    .get()
    .join(' ')
  )
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Names: <input type="text" id="title" class="personName" />
<input type="text" id="firstName" class="personName" />
<input type="text" id="lastName" class="personName" />
<br/>
<input type="text" class="displayName" />
```